# Map an object in List<DropDown>

Tags: java, mapping, response, hibernate-mapping

Assume the `getter()` method returns `List<Object>`. Assume the `Object` class has `getFirstName()`, `getLastName()`, and trying to do the following.

```
public List<<String,String>> getSomethingElse(@QueryParam("Id") Long Id) {
    getter(id).stream().map(p -> new PDropDown<Object>(?).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want this to return only `firstName` and `LastName`. How can I map the object so it returns only those two?

Comment: `List<<String,String>>` what is this type ?

Comment: Please provide compilable code that can be analyzed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the getter() method has to return a specific type for example `List<Person>` rather than `List<Object>` otherwise you have to cast it.
The idea would be to map  `firstName` and the `lastName` to a  `PDropDown` instance that provides a constructor that accepts them :

You could do that :

```
List<DropDown> result =  
    getter(id).stream()
              .map(p -> new PDropDown(p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If `getter()` returns `List<Object>`, you could  throw an exception if one of the elements returned is not a `Person` :

```
List<DropDown> result =  
    getter(id).stream()
              .map( o -> { if (o instanceof Person){
                             Person p = (Person) o;
                             return new PDropDown(p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName()); 
                          }
                          throw new IllegalArgumentException("o "+ o + " is not a Person");
                         })
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```